# How to determine which nested generator produces StopIteration exception?

Tags: python-3.x

I bumped into a situation where I need to determine in my `try/except` code which nested generator is raising a `StopIteration` exception. How do I do it? The following is a dummy example:

```
def genOne(iMax, jMax):
    i = 0;
    g2 = genTwo(jMax)
    while i <= iMax:
        print('genOne: ' + str(i))
        next(g2)
        yield
        i = i + 1

def genTwo(jMax):
    j = 0;
    while j <= jMax:
        print('genTwo: ' + str(j))
        yield
        j = j + 1

g1 = genOne(6, 3)        # The inputs are arbitrary numbers
try:
    while True:
        next(g1)    
except:  
    # Do some processing depending on who generates the StopIteration exception
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you have `genOne` handle the exception?

Comment: In the real problem, I have no access to the generators. Assume that generators cannot be modified, can I easily determine it?

Answer (score 2):

This can be generalized to the problem of finding the origin of an arbitrary exception.

Use the [`traceback` module](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/traceback.html) to inspect the stacktrace of your exception object.

Here is a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1095656/923794) on a similar subject.

Some example code:

```
g1 = genOne(6, 3)        # The inputs are arbitrary numbers
try:
    while True:
        next(g1)    
except:
    exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()
    print(traceback.extract_tb(exc_traceback)[-1])
```

Shell output:

```
> ./test.py
genOne: 0
genTwo: 0
genOne: 1
genTwo: 1
genOne: 2
genTwo: 2
genOne: 3
genTwo: 3
genOne: 4
('./test.py', 12, 'genOne', 'next(g2)')
```

Note that the `[-1]` in the `extract_tb()` call explicitly checks only the first lower level of the stacktrace. With the print you can see which element of that output you'd need to check (`genOne` -> item index #2 in that list). In your particular example you'd probably want to check if the lowest level generator string `genTwo` exists in any of the elements of the `traceback.extract_tb(exc_traceback)` array.

Those hardcoded checks relying on internal code details are been frowned upon, *especially* since in your particular example you do not have control over their implementation.